# C++/CLI Access String::Format from non CLI Code

Tags: c++, c++-cli, variadic-templates, variadic-functions, managed-c++

I want to access the String::Format Method from my C++ codebase. To do so I could simply create a function:

```
template<typename... ArgTypes>
void FormatAString(CString& format, ArgTypes... args)
{
    String^ toFormat = gcnew String(format);
    format = String::Format(toFormat, args...);
}
```

My problem is, that not every file in my codebase is CLI and I want to call this method from the non-managed part. To be able to do that usually I declare the methods in a header file and implement them in a managed .cpp file.

Because I am using a parameter pack here i can not separate the implementation of the method from the declaration. So the solution, or better, workaround I came up with is the folliwing:

```
//My header file

template<typename... ArgTypes>
void FormatAString(CString& format, ArgTypes... args);
```

In the header file i declared the method like I normally would.

```
// My cpp file
template<typename... ArgTypes>
void FormatAString(CString& format, ArgTypes... args)
{
    String^ toFormat = gcnew String(format);
    format = String::Format(toFormat, args...);
}

void tempMethod()
{
    int i;
    FormatAString(CString("Hello"), i);
    FormatAString(CString("Hello"), i, i);
    FormatAString(CString("Hello"), i, i, i);
    FormatAString(CString("Hello"), i, i, i, i); 
    FormatAString(CString("Hello"), i, i, i, i, i);
    FormatAString(CString("Hello"), i, i, i, i, i, i);
}
```

To get the linker to work I created a temp method (I learned this is possible here: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/48575/How-to-define-a-template-class-in-a-h-file-and-imp)

The problem is, that I would have to add every possible combination of types that I later want to use to the tempMethod which is not a permanent solution.

So if I want to call `FormatAString(CString("Hello {0}", "World");` from somewhere in my code I would have to add something like this to the tempMethod:

`const char* c;
FormatAString(CString("Hello"), c);`

Is there a better way to separate the declaration from the implementation?
This is my first question on SO, I hope this is enough information.

Comment: Bad idea in more than one way.  You can't bypass the fundamental limitation that templates don't have external linkage, the implementation must appear in a header file.  And you can't bypass the fundamental requirement that using managed code, like String::Format(), requires compiling with /clr.  This can't go anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#include <atlstr.h>



#pragma managed(push, on) 
using namespace System;

template<typename... ArgTypes>
void FormatAString(CString& format, ArgTypes... args)
{
    String^ toFormat = gcnew String(format);
    format = String::Format(toFormat, args...);
}

#pragma managed(pop) 
#pragma managed(off) 

void test()
{
    CString a("{0} {1} {2} {0} ");
    FormatAString(a, 1, 10.2, 10.0f);
}
```

However if you pass string literal, you get an error, because the compiler (vs2017)  complains it cannot convert a cli::array ...